# How to use scoped services within a in C# worker process using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am creating C# worker process and having trouble defining dependency.

I have a class called `VMValidationManager` which implements interface `IVMValidationManager`

```
public interface IVMValidationManager
{
    void RunVMValidationScripts();
}

public class VMValidationManager : IVMValidationManager
{
    List<string> failedScripts = new List<string>();
}
```

Also i have `Worker` class in which i want to inject `IVMValidationManager`

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IVMValidationManager _vmValidationManager;

public Worker(IVMValidationManager vmValidationManager)
{
    _vmValidationManager = vmValidationManager;
}


protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    _vmValidationManager.RunVMValidationScripts();
}
}
```

In Program.cs i have this code

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddScoped<IVMValidationManager, VMValidationManager>();
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
}
```

When run i am getting error. stack trace

```
Cannot consume scoped service 'VMAgent.Services.IVMValidationManager' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.


   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite scopedCallSite, CallSiteValidatorState state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, CallSiteValidatorState state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, CallSiteValidatorState state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceProviderEngineCallback.OnCreate(ServiceCallSite callSite)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't registered any service `VMValidationManager`. You've registered a service `IVMValidationManager`. You can therefore inject `IVMValidationManager` but not `VMValidationManager`.

Comment: @Llama. Ok. i updated the code (in my question as well) but same error.

Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: VMAgent.Worker': Cannot consume scoped service 'VMAgent.Services.IVMValidationManager' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)

Comment: @Pankaj: You have injected ILogger but not register the implementation

Comment: @LeVu, i tried removing iLogger , no luck.

Comment: @Pankaj: Do you have the full stack trace?

Comment: @LeVu, added stack trace in question

Comment: AddSingleton()...

Comment: @Pankaj: according the message in stack trace. the IVMValidationManager should be registered at Singleton scope.

Comment: @LeVu,  TheGeneral, adding singleton worked. does it mean , in C# worker process project, we can't add other scopes than Singleton?

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a *scoped* service to a *singleton*, all things being equal, just `AddSingleton`

```
services.AddSingleton<IVMValidationManager, VMValidationManager>();
services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

There is lots of documentation on this.. however start with
[Service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes)

> **Do not** resolve a scoped service from a singleton and be careful not to
> do so indirectly, for example, through a transient service. It may
> cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent
> requests. It's fine to:
>
> - Resolve a singleton service from a scoped or transient service.
> - Resolve a scoped service from another scoped or transient service.

Comment: Although changing the lifestyle from Scoped to Singleton might work, there is usually a reason that the component is registered as Scoped. For instance because it can't be used in a thread-safe manner (as is, for instance, the case with `DbContext` classes). I, therefore, find the simple advise to change the lifestyle to singleton dangerous and too simplistic. This answer should -at least- show a warning of what's the risk of increasing the lifestyle, and preferably describe how to solve the problem when the component's lifestyle can't be changed.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also point to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service) in the Microsoft documentation, as it shows how to Use scoped services within a BackgroundService.

Comment: @Steven all though what you say is correct and I appreciate the comments, this wasn't an article about the benefits of scoped and all the use cases, it was merely about the error. I mean, you could also make the case for all the less than optimal use cases for scoped and why it doesn't make sense to push them into a service which is long running and a singleton. The truth be known, for a long running service, the naming of the ops service, the confusion about the error, and the fact that I linked to a rather concisely written documentation on lifecycles, I believe that answer was adequate